# how to change timezone of timestamp data

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Belgrade');
```

Now, I'm getting data from a mysql table / a timestamp column named `date`

```
echo date("d. m. H:i", strtotime(htmlspecialchars($r['date'])))
```

Result is (for example) - `10. 09. 02:36`

So, it works, but not in desired timezone. Displayed data are from server's location timezone.

How can I get the data recalculated according to my timezone?

Comment: whats the format of `$r['date']`?

Comment: @Ghost, `date` is timestamp column name, inside mysql table. `$r['date']` is (I suppose) something like `read the column 'date'`

Comment: so the format is `2014-09-10 00:00:00`

Answer (score 2):

I faced nearly same problem and this is what i did

```
$mdate=new DateTime($date);
$mdate->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne'));
$newtime= $mdate->format("jS F, Y h:i:s a");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
 $timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
 date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
 echo date("d. m. H:i", strtotime(htmlspecialchars($r['date'])))
```

This will provide you the correct result

Comment: Vineet, what is the difference between your code and the code in my post.

Comment: You want to store the date according to your time zone

Answer (score 0):

> Now check this code.

```
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $date = date('m/d/Y');
        $time = date('h:i'); 
        echo $date;
        echo $time;
```